# best practice - How to generate a very large MS Word File in Java

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, docx, docx4j

Our customer want's to generate a *ms word file (docx)* with over 90'000 pages inside. Each page should be created based on a *template ms word fil*e.

To solve this issue, we are using the *Docx4j Enterprise Edition* library at the moment but it takes over 1.5h to generate this file.

The long processing time is the reason why we are getting a timeout after 60 minutes from the IE-Browser 9 which is used by our customer mainly.

Link: [Microsoft KB - IE Timeout](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181050)

So how could we improve the performance to generate the large ms word docx files ?

- application: jee with java 6
- tomcat 6

Thank you

Comment: You can avoid timeout to responding directly and processing docx in another thread. After you can notify the user, maybe by mail because in 1.5h we don't where he is...

Comment: Yes, this should run async. You could response immediately with an URI where the client can get the current status and use long polling for example. Apart from that I would investigate what is the bottleneck in your generation. Is it CPU, memory, I/O limited or is there a complex algorithm with O(n^2)?

Comment: Are you merging your documents in a single thread, one after the other?  You could merge in parallel (matching the number of server cores), then merge the results ... Are you using DocumentBuilderIncremental?  But what are you going to do with a 90K page Word document? Can Word open it?

Comment: @simdevmon: our customer's server has the following specs 8GB Memory, 2 Core Prozessor, Windows 2003 Server 32 BIT. No complex algo implemented by us but may be inside docxj4 library

Comment: @JasonPlutext: First we tried merging by using DocumentBuilderIncremental but it was slower than using BlockRange-ArrayList and DocumentBuilder.

We tried also to process 90’000 recs to 90’000 pages in a single docx but it fails with OutofMemoryException ‚Java Heap space‘, so we did implement a limitation of 2500 pages per Word Docx-file.

So that means, in case of 90’000 recs, our application will create 36 docx files and ZIP them to one archive... kind of workaround

Comment: You could then use DBI to merge the 36 x 2500 page documents.  You should also consider progress reporting (see the MergeDocxProgress sample) - and a decent server!  Are you setting -Xmx?

Comment: @blub: Did you monitor how much the hardware resources are utilized during document generation? Windows Server 2013 32 bits supports only 4GB memory as far as I know.

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Is the DBI not processing the task in memory as well? Of course, we’ve tried several settings to use Xmx, but the ram was being filled up anyways. What are your experience when generating docs files of this size ? how long should it take ?

Comment: @simdevmon: We have monitored the whole process several times with different file sizes. And the result was always the same. The more „pages“ you process, the more the memory gets filled up. Until it reaches the max available ram, then the outofmemory error occur.

Comment: Few quick suggestions that I didn't verify. MS Word has no limit on page count, but has a limit with the text size that cannot exceed to 32MB. Then, have you tried to use DITA converter ? Finally, have you tried to monitor Object creation and then adjust the Heap Space to suit your needs ?

Comment: DBI keeps just 2 documents in memory: the current source document, and the target document.

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Of course, but in our case the target document grows up during the DBI processing and allocate more and more memory. At least, it does performs slower than the DocumentBuilder. That's why we limited the numbers of pages to 2500. Do you have an example how we should implement a fast and memory-reduced docx-generation ? So that we will be able to solve the timeout and heap space problem. Thanks for any advise.

Comment: What code are you using to invoke DBI?  Please email support@plutext.com